# Ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_4[X]/(X^2+X+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to find (maximal) ideals of $\Bbb{Q}[X]/(X^2)$ and $\Bbb{Z}_4[X]/(X^2+X+1)$. 
for the 1st one I can do this, because $(x)$ is a maximal and $(x)^2=0$.

---

Now, I want to know how ideals (specially maximal ideals) of $\Bbb{Z}_4[X]/(X^2+X+1)$ looks like? there are many difficulties: $\Bbb{Z}$ is not field, I cant decompose $X^2+X+1$ ...

thnx for help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You got the first ok. A good hint for the second depends quite a bit on your background. I will lead off by giving a suggestion. You should comment if the terms sound all Greek to you.

Comment: A plan of attack (prove, review, connect the dots). 1) An ideal $M$ of a commutative ring $R$ is maximal if and only if $R/M$ is a field. 2) Polynomial division (by a **monic** polynomial) shows that any coset of $(x^2+x+1)$ in $\Bbb{Z}_4[x]$ has a unique representative of degree $<2$. 3) Therefore that second ring has $16$ elements, and therefore the characteristic of $R/M$ is two. 4) Therefore every maximal ideal contains the element $2$. 5) $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$.

Comment: thanks. 1,2,3 are ok. but 4 and 5... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, you are right that $(x)$ is a maximal ideal of $R=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2)$, where $x$ is the image of $X$ under the canonical projection $\mathbb{Q}[X]\to R$.  But it is also the only ideal of $R$ that is proper and nonzero.  In other words, all ideals of $R$ are $\{0\}$, $(x)$, and $R$.

To show this, suppose $I$ is a ideal of $R$ such that $I\neq \{0\}$ and $I\neq R$.  Recall that every element of $R$ can be written as $ax+b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$.  If $I$ contains $ax+b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $(a,b)\neq (0,0)$, then $a\neq 0$ (otherwise, $I$ contains $1$ and $I=R$).  That is, we can assume without loss of generality that $a=1$.

Now, if $I$ contains $x+b$, then it contains $$(x-b)(x+b)=x^2-b^2=-b^2.$$  If $b\neq 0$, then $I$ contains $1$, and $I=R$ is a contradiction.  Hence, $b=0$, and so every nonzero element of $I$ is of the form $kx$ where $k\in\mathbb{Q}$ is such that $k\neq 0$.  That is, $I=(x)$.  (Note that $R/(x)$ is indeed a field, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.)

---

Now, let $S$ be the ring $\mathbb{Z}_4[X]/(X^2+X+1)$.  (I assume that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is the ring of integers modulo $4$.)   Denote by $x$ the image of $X$ under the canonical projection $\mathbb{Z}_4[X]\to S$.  Any element of $S$ can be written as $ax+b$ such that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_4$.  Let $I$ be an ideal of $S$ such that $I\neq \{0\}$ and $I\neq S$.

If $I$ contain a nonzero constant, then $I=(2)$ (otherwise $1\in I$, and so $I=S$).  If $I$ contains an element $ax+b$ with $a=1$ or $a=3$, then we can assume that $a=1$ since $3=-1$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_4$.  Now, $$(x^2+x+1)-(b^2-b+1)=x^2+x+b(1-b)=(x+1-b)(x+b)\in I.$$
Because $x^2+x+1=0$, we get $b^2-b+1\in I$.  But $b^2-b+1$ is an odd element of $\mathbb{Z}_4$, so it is invertible.  This means $I$ contains $1$, and $I=S$, a contradiction.

Hence, if $I$ contains $ax+b$ with $a\neq 0$, then $a=2$.  Now, suppose that $2x+1\in I$.  Then,
$$2(x^2+x+1)-(x+2)=2x^2+x=x(2x+1)\in I.$$
So, $x+2\in I$, and $1=(2x+1)-2(x+2)\in I$.  This is again a contradiction, as it leads to $I=S$.  So, $2x+1\notin I$.  Similarly, $2x-1$ cannot be in $I$.

We have now proven that $I$ contains either $2x$ or $2x+2$.  If $2x\in I$, then
$$2x+2=2(x^2+x+1)+(2x+2)=2x^2=x(2x)\in I\,.$$
Similarly, if $2x+2\in I$, then $2x\in I$.  If $2x$ and $2x+2$ are in $I$, then $2=(2x+2)-(2x)\in I$.  That is, $I=\{0,2,2x,2x+2\}=(2)$.

In summary, $S$ has only three ideals: $\{0\}$, $(2)$, and $S$.  The maximal ideal of $S$ is of course $(2)$.  (Note that $S/(2)$ is indeed a field, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_4=\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)$.)

Comment: thank you  Zvi. is $(X^2+X+1)$ reducible in $\Bbb{Z}_4[X]$?

Comment: No, it is not.  If it were reducible, then it would have a linear factor, and so it must have a root in $\mathbb{Z}_4$.  But $x^2+x+1$ is odd for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.